# Does restarting sshd always keep existing sessions alive?

Tags: ssh, sshd

I booted a server and (too late) I discovered that some breaking change had been made to /etc/ssh/sshd.conf. Can I be reasonably sure that restarting sshd keeps existing connections ? (this was on solaris, but question also applies to ubuntu)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can be (reasonably) sure that your current connection will not break when you restart `sshd`. If you want to be on the safe side, simply send a `SIGHUP` to your running instance and it will re-read its configuration file.

Comment: Indeed. Straight from the authoritative source [sshd rereads its configuration file when it receives a hangup signal, SIGHUP](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8). Tested with `

Comment: See also `sshd -t`  [Test mode. Only check the validity of the configuration file and sanity of the keys. This is useful for updating sshd reliably as configuration options may change.](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd&sec=8)