# Automated forwarding to reverse tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a Raspberry Pi (remote) which is behind a NAT. In order to access it from my home computer (local), I connect it to my ASW server (server) via reverse tunnel as described in various posts.

Remote connects to server:

```
ssh -f -N -T -R22222:localhost:22 -i ssh-ec2/ec-key.pem ec2-user@xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
```

I can then connect to my ASW server via SSH and once I'm logged in I can connect to my Raspberry via:

```
ssh -p 22222 pi@localhost
```

That all works fine.

My problem now is, that I want to do remote session with intellij from my local directly to my remote Raspberry. For that I need to connect to my server via SSH and then manually enter again the connected to my remote.

How can I set up a tunnel so I can connect to my server, but directly to port `22222`? I have tried the following from my local machine, but the connection times out:

```
ssh -l 9999:localhost:22222 ec2-user@52.201.173.131 -i c:/privatekey.pem
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong? Sorry I'm totally new to Linux, so apologies if that's a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect from your ASW server, you connect to `localhost`. Note what [`man 1 ssh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh) says:

> `-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport`
>
> […]
>
> By default, the listening socket on the server will be bound to the loopback interface only. This may be overridden by specifying a `bind_address`. An empty `bind_address`, or the address `*`, indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces. Specifying a remote `bind_address` will only succeed if the server's `GatewayPorts` option is enabled (see `sshd_config(5)`).

Then [`man 5 sshd_config`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) says:

> `GatewayPorts`
>
> Specifies whether remote hosts are allowed to connect to ports forwarded for the client. By default, `sshd(8)` binds remote port forwardings to the loopback address. This prevents other remote hosts from connecting to forwarded ports. `GatewayPorts` can be used to specify that `sshd` should allow remote port forwardings to bind to non-loopback addresses, thus allowing other hosts to connect. The argument may be `no` to force remote port forwardings to be available to the local host only, `yes` to force remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address, or `clientspecified` to allow the client to select the address to which the forwarding is bound. The default is `no`.

To make it work you should do something like this:

- include `GatewayPorts clientspecified` in `sshd_config` on the server (and restart/reload the daemon, see [*Is there any backup for `ssh` configuration, to roll back on error?*](https://superuser.com/a/1261311/432690), [*Does restarting `sshd` always keep existing sessions alive?*](https://superuser.com/a/60410/432690) and [*Restart SSH on a machine where SSH is the only mode of access*](https://serverfault.com/a/141208));
- connect with `ssh … -R :22222:localhost:22 …` from the Raspberry (note the first `:`, it separates empty `bind_address` from `port`).